# Strange horizontal scroll on mobile viewing of site (Possibly iPhone only)

Tags: css, ios, wordpress, mobile

When viewing a mobile project I'm working on from an iPhone I'm noticing that I can drag to the left and a right margin appears.. unsure how to fix this? Help is greatly appreciated!!

http://demo6.abcguide.com/

Comment: Post a small test case, not just a link to a live site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting `overflow: hidden` on the `html` element. Seemed to solve the problem on desktop Webkit.

Comment: That didn't quite work, but adding overflow:hidden to the body element did the trick! Thank you, definitely wouldn't have figured that out on my own thought process. :)